# Why is there a "...being..." in this sentence: "There was little evidence from trials of it being of benefit."

Tags: grammar, meaning

This is about a new drug, which was approved in the US, but was rejected in the EU for not being safe enough.

**At the time, many scientists said there was little evidence from trials of it being of benefit despite it targeting amyloid - a protein that forms abnormal clumps in the brains of people with Alzheimer's.** [BBC-alzheimer drug rejected](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/health-59699907)

I didn't understand what **"......being of benefit...."** is referring to. Also, I didn't understand why there is a "....being of benefit..." rather than "...evidence of benefit...".

I am confused. Is the expression **"being of benefit"** referring to **"...trials of it..."** or is it referring to the word **"..evidence..."**?

In other words, does it mean;

1- There is little evidence of benefit.

2- The trials are not quite beneficial.

Comment: Non-native speakers are often puzzled because they group the wrong words together. **From trials** describes the evidence - there was little evidence **of it** (the drug) being of benefit (that it was of benefit).

Comment: idiomatic uses/usage: to be of benefit, to be of use, to be of value to someone or something.

Comment: @Kate Bunting, That was exactly what I needed. You break it down so clearly, I can now see what words I should group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a mint-condition 1980 Ferrari with only 500 miles on the odometer:

> There is little doubt (that) *it will be expensive*.

Above we provide a declarative tensed clause as the complement, *it will be expensive.* But we can also use "doubt **of**", and the preposition requires a nominal object, **it**, and that pronoun is in turn complemented by an *untensed* clause:

> There is little doubt **of** *it being expensive*.

Was the car damaged in any way?

> There is no evidence (that) *it was damaged*.
>
> There is no evidence **of** *it being damaged*.

The adjective "damaged" could be replaced by a prepositional phrase with a similar meaning:

> There is no evidence of it being *in a collision*.

Similarly, in your sentence, the prepositional phrase **of benefit** could be replaced by an adjective:

> There is little evidence of it being *of benefit*.
>
> There is little evidence of it being *beneficial*.

Answer (score 1):

The verb "to be" is one of the more complex in English. Shakespeare was famous for saying...

> To be or not to be, that is the question... (*Hamlet*)

If I choose to be happy, then I am being happy. The construct "being" (the present participle of the verb "to be") means "experiencing or existing in the state of." Being happy means experiencing happiness.

There are other ways to say what the BBC announcer said. For example:

> At the time, many scientists said trials demonstrated little evidence of benefit despite...

But the announcer's use of "being of" is quite reasonable.

*Specifically...*

"Benefit" must describe the value of the drug, not the value of the trial. Using "being of" achieves this.